# socket.io-client-cpp does not connect to node app on Heroku via https

Tags: node.js, heroku, https, websocket, socket.io

`socket.io-client.cpp` does not connect to node app on Heroku while Node JS `socket.io-client` does without any problem. Error is:

```
[2018-12-11 19:32:43] [connect] Successful connection 
[2018-12-11 19:32:43] [error] handle_read_http_response error: websocketpp.transport:7 (End of File) 
[2018-12-11 19:32:43] [info] Error getting remote endpoint: system:107
```

Changed URL from `https` to `http`://myapp.heroku.com - works now.  Is it possible to connect via `https` as well? JS `socket.io-client` connects via secure connection without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have built `socket.io-client-cpp` app with `SIO_TLS` in `DEFINES` (compiler flag: `-DSIO_TLS`) - connects via `https` fine now! This enables `TLS` support as mentioned here:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/pull/137

Answer (score 1):

I have spent days trying to find a solution, reading through the documentation back and forth, and found nothing. I also saw the linked pull request but couldn't make sense of it.

Eventually, I added `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-DSIO_TLS` to the `portfile.cmake` through this post, and that finally worked!

I am using vcpkg with MSBuild, which is integrated into Visual Studio 2022. After the first installation of packages, there is a folder "AppData\Local\vcpkg\registries\git-trees". In this folder, there is also a folder "2aa8fb06982abcd0918726ba79bf81edc9000a4b" (though it might vary), and therein the "portfile.cmake".

This is the configuration I am using:

```
vcpkg_cmake_configure(
  SOURCE_PATH "${SOURCE_PATH}"
  OPTIONS
    -DUSE_SUBMODULES=OFF
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=include
    "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-DSIO_TLS"
)
```

Afterwards, simply delete the `vcpkg_installed` folder and let it rebuild. After that, https worked for me.